# Cannot retrieve column information from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, namely user_info and comments. I want to join the tables, so i can relate the `user_id` from the from comments after the inner join has happened, which will join based on the id columns. The whole reason for this is so i can find out what the id is of a user who posts a comment on a users profile, which i store in user_id.

SHOW CREATE TABLE user_info

```
CREATE TABLE `user_info` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `joined` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)) 
   ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=64 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci'
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE comments

```
'CREATE TABLE `comments` (
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comment` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `date_posted` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL)
  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci'
```

The query code

```
try {
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT user_id
                            FROM comments 
                                INNER JOIN user_info USING (id) 
                            WHERE id = :user");

    $result->bindParam(':user', $post_session_user_id);
    $result->execute();
    $comment_details = $result->fetch();
}
```

How comment_details is stored

```
$comment_id = $comment_details[0];
```

and then i do a var_dump that returns `NULL`

```
var_dump($comment_id);
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: What's in `$comment_details`?

Comment: If you run the query directly against the database with that particular value, do you get any records?

Comment: @DanBracuk Yeah it returns what i'd expect from the database when i do it in WorkBench.

Comment: @didierc the results from the query

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not be using `USING` as that works only when you have 2 fields, one in each table both having the same name.

In your tables comment.user_id holds the user_info.id

So your query should probably be

```
SELECT user_id
FROM comments 
    INNER JOIN user_info ON user_info.id = comments.user_id
WHERE comments.id = :user
```

Comment: There seems to be an error in the syntax you posted above. Also both tables have a column `id` which obviously share the same name.

Comment: The syntax error is nothing you can't cope with I trust.  Regarding the id fields, they might have the same name but they don't represent the same thing.

Comment: Ah, i fixed syntax error, was me being an idiot. Still don't seem to get any results though, still returns null. Except when i run the code in WorkBench, in which case it returns the correct information

Comment: Add the comments.id field to the select clause and see if it's the same as the user_id.  Might simply be a fluke.

Comment: @DanBracuk That also returns what you expect it to in WorkBench

Comment: In your comments table, how many records have the user_id = id?  How many records have user_id <> id?

Comment: One of each at the moment

Comment: Run your query again for the other comment.